# Downloading the zip file through api c# unauthorized - error

Tags: c#, .net

I create an application that is designed to collect data from Account on site FreshMail.
All the basic information I was able to download without any problem. Unfortunately, when I try to download data subscribers, api needs to send a request for the zip file.
I made such a request, but when try to download a file I getting an authorization error.

The code should work as follows (according to what is available in the documentation):

1. I am sending the request for the preparation of the file, and in response get the ID that will help me to check the status of preparation of the file and download it.
2. Then check the status of preparation of the file (status is ok).
3. Finally, I try to download a file - and here there is an error authorization.

There is a code:

```
 responseidjob = wrapper.ExecuteRequest("async_subscribers_list/export", configuration, new { list = hashcode });

            IDictionary<string, object> Input = responseidjob.GetResponse();

            foreach (dynamic all in Input.ToList())
            {
                if (all.Key == "data")
                {
                    foreach (dynamic allin in all.Value)
                    {
                        idJob = allin.Value.ToString();
                    }
                }
            }

            if (idJob != "")
            {
                responsecheck = wrapper.ExecuteRequest("async_result/get", configuration, new { id_job = idJob });

                configuration.SetContentType("application/zip");
                responsezip = wrapper.ExecuteRequest("async_result/getFile", configuration, new { id_job = idJob });
            }
```

Comment: What is `wrapper` and what api are you using?

Comment: It contains objects:
HttpStatusCode? GetHttpStatusCode();
string GetRawResponse();       
dynamic GetResponse();
List<RestError> GetRestErrors();
WebExceptionStatus? GetWebExceptionStatus();
bool IsResponseRaw();
bool IsSuccessful();

It is FreshMail api, 
the library is available here: [link]https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/731785/freshmail_dot_net_wrappers.zip[link]

Comment: I want to Give as much information, but I'm new to the API integrations

Comment: This api? https://freshmail.com/developer-api/samples-wrappers/

Comment: Yes, exactly this one